# GL_POINTS glitch on Windows

Tags: opengl, glut

I have a strange bug affecting my GLUT program

```
void display(void) {
/* clear the screen to the clear colour */
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

jVector** buff = antialias ? antialiasedBuffer : screen;
for (int y = 0; y < sceneModel.height(); ++y){
    for (int x = 0; x < sceneModel.width(); ++x){
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            glColor3d(buff[x][y].x, buff[x][y].y, buff[x][y].z);
            glVertex2f(x,y);
        glEnd();
    }
}

/* swap buffers */
glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape (int w, int h) {
/* set the viewport */
glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);

/* Matrix for projection transformation */
glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION); 

/* replaces the current matrix with the identity matrix */
glLoadIdentity ();

/* Define a 2d orthographic projection matrix */
gluOrtho2D (0.0, (GLdouble) w, 0.0, (GLdouble) h);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

// PROJECT CODE

sceneModel.generateProjectModel();
screen = rayTrace(sceneModel);

// OPENGL CODE

/* deal with any GLUT command Line options */
glutInit(&argc, argv);

/* create an output window */
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(sceneModel.width(), sceneModel.height());

/* set the name of the window and try to create it */
glutCreateWindow("CS 488 - Project 3");

/* specify clear values for the color buffers */
glClearColor (0, 0, 0, 1.0);

  /* Receive keyboard inputs */
glutKeyboardFunc (Keyboard);

  /* assign the display function */
glutDisplayFunc(display);

/* assign the idle function */
glutIdleFunc(display);

  /* sets the reshape callback for the current window */
glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

  /* enters the GLUT event processing loop */
glutMainLoop();

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

What happens is that the rendered image shows some random vertical black lines. I can assure you that the buffer doesn't have them. And this only happens using the GL_POINTS drawing, when i use GL_LINES these lines don't show up. I also noticed that compiling it on a mac doesn't lead to this glitch. Also, after resizing the window, the number and the position of the black lines change, as it can be seen from the second and third images.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 2 after resizing window]

Comment: Why don't you just draw a textured quad? Or for bob's sake, use at least glDrawPixels. Anyway, you're probably running into some roundoff error somewhere in the transform pipeline.

Comment: Can you provide me some examples on how to draw a textured quad? I couldn't find any

Comment: There are several OpenGL tutorials out there. Look for "OpenGL texture mapping tutorial". For the modern OpenGL approach see http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Texturing/Texturing.html – if you're looking for the old and dusted method, I'd say have a look at the (mostly outdated) NeHe texturing tutorial. http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_mapping/12038/ –– Anyway, computer graphics is all about moving data around as fast as possible. You found the most arcane and slowest way to draw pixel data to a viewport. Just don't do it the way you did. \*Shudder\*

Answer (score 3):

That's about the *slowest possible way* to blit a bitmap to the framebuffer.  At least move your `glBegin()/glEnd()` pair outside the `for`-loops!

Try uploading your bitmap to a texture and rendering a viewport-sized textured quad instead.

Comment: This is not about performances, and since i am doing raytracing I don't care about it, also because this loop is not certaintly the bottleneck.
The bug still happens anyway.
About the texture quad, I will try it.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. Content generated using the CPU should always be put in a texture and displayed. It is fairly straight forward. It also lets you resize the result to any size. Just be aware of texture interpolation.